# How do I resize a textview and scrollview content size based on dynamic content

Tags: uiscrollview, uitextview

I have a scrollview that contains an image and a single textview. The content of the textview is dynamic it could be 200 in height or it could be 1500 in height. I am using storyboard so how do I setup both the textview and the scrollview content size to allow for dynamic content in the textview. I can set them both to arbitrarily high number but then I end up with a bunch empty space in the scrollview. I want both the image and the text to scrolling on and off the screen as required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would use constraints. Here is an example of how I did it with a scrollview. With a textview it is scrollable, and doesn't require you to set a content size, you simply put the content in it. If you want to control the viewable area of the uitextview, you will need to adjust it to what you see fit based on the amount of text you have, font and spacing you use.

```
    NSDictionary *viewsDic = @{
        @"image":image,
        @"text": text,
        @"lable":label,
        @"someview":someview,
        @"anotherview":anotherview};

    [someview addConstraints:
        [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[image(320)]|"
                                                options:0
                                                metrics:0
                                                  views:viewsDic]];
    [someview addConstraints:
        [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[image]|"
                                                options:0
                                                metrics:0
                                                  views:viewsDic]];
    [someview addConstraints:
        [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-14-[label]"
                                                        @"[text(<=200)]"
                                                options:0
                                                metrics:0
                                                  views:viewsDic]];
    [someview addConstraints:
        [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-22-[txtDollarAmountFront(==37)]"
                                                options:0
                                                metrics:0
                                                  views:viewsDic]];
    [someview addConstraints:
        [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-19-[label]"
                                                options:0
                                                metrics:0
```